# Firefox or pantheon window render bug?

Tags: pantheon, firefox, xorg

The latest Firefox update gives a really weird double window.

[image]

Anyone else facing this? Can somebody please clarify?

Thanks!

Oy! it's gone when title-bar was hid.

[image]

Comment: Also having this issue, but only after the latest Firefox update 81. This is also the case with all Firefox modals, like About.

Comment: yep, that's right

Comment: I've opened an issue here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1671070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was a Firefox [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1666839). Fixed in Firefox `85.0`, current stable release `84.0`.

[image]